# Authentication problems within Google Cloud AutoML

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, nlp, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-automl

I was doing the Google Cloud AutoML demo for entity extraction and I ran into a few authentication problems. I created the model using the examples they gave us, and I have my model created and deployed. However, I can't seem to actually seem to get my data. Here's the [tutorial section](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/predict#automl_language_entity_extraction_predict-python) I'm using and here's the [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/automl-refactor/automl/cloud-client/language_entity_extraction_predict.py) that I'm trying to run.

I filled in the correct project_id and model_id, but the thing is I can't seem to run the program without getting this error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest>py retrieveresult.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 824, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 726, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "The caller does not have permission"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1578714342.247000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.14.74:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"The caller does not have permission","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retrieveresult.py", line 20, in <module>
    response = prediction_client.predict(model_full_id, payload)
  File "C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\automl_v1\gapic\prediction_service_client.py", line 322, in predict
    return self._inner_api_calls["predict"](
  File "C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 281, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\willi\Documents\machinelearningtest\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission
```

I can't figure out how to use the service accounts in my code to get permission... is it possible to get some pointers? This is my first time using something like this.

Comment: How are you setting up the service account for your application? What roles are assigned to the service account? Edit your question with more details. You are not specifying a service account in your code, so that means you are using ADC (Application Default Credentials) and the libraries are locating the credentials for you. Google search Google Cloud ADC and follow the documentation for setup.

Answer (score 0):

From the official GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/before-you-begin):

1. Make sure the AutoML API is enabled for your project - [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/automl.googleapis.com?q=AutoML)
2. Create a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account) which you will use for the authentication - *service accounts are the only authentication option available with the AutoML API*.
3. Create and download [key file](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey?project=) for that service account.
4. Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path to the service account key file that you downloaded when you created the service account:

   - `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key-file`
5. Set the `PROJECT_ID` environment variable to your Project ID. The AutoML API calls and resource names include your Project ID in them. The PROJECT_ID environment variable provides a convenient way to specify the ID:

   - `export PROJECT_ID=your-project-id`
6. If you are an owner for your project, add your service account to the **AutoML Editor** IAM role, replacing *"service-account-name"* with the name of your new service account. For example, `service-account1@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com`:

---

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
   --member="serviceAccount:service-account-name" \
   --role="roles/automl.editor"
```

---

7. If you are not a project owner, ask a project owner to add both your user ID and your service account to the AutoML Editor IAM role